# Grails file uploading using restful-api plugin

Tags: rest, grails, plugins, groovy

My Config.groovy file reads:

```
resource 'ktm-documents' config{
serviceName ='docCompositeService'
// methods = ['list']
representation {
    mediaTypes = ["application/vnd.hedtech.v1+json", "application/json", "multipart/form-data"]
    marshallers{
        jsonBeanMarshaller{
            supports net.hedtech.banner.decorator.DocDecorator
        }
        jsonBeanMarshaller{
            supports net.hedtech.banner.decorator.Indexes
        }
    }
    extractor = new  net.hedtech.banner.extractor.DocExtractor()
}
}
```

The extractor is:

```
class DocExtractor implements RequestExtractor{
@Override
Map extract(HttpServletRequest request) {
print("========== My EXTRACTOR ========")
MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr
Map responseMap = [:]
print request

try {
   print "Here's abc " + request.getParameter("abc")

   mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
   CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("file");


    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        responseMap.put("error","file empty hai")
    } else {
        responseMap.put("file", file)
    }

print responseMap.values()

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace()
}
}
}
```

When trying to fetch the file which was extracted from request in the extractor inside the create() of service, I get **"Cannot get property 'file' of null"** error.

The create() method in service:

```
def create(Map params){

print params
File f = params.file

return ["File Uploaded!"]
}
```

Any thoughts on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the code.

The request that was being sent from the POSTMAN REST client, had a **Content-Type** declared in it.

Please note that we shouldn't mention the **Content-Type** even while sending across a multipart/form-data request.

That worked.